# R.java not getting updated

Tags: android, r.java-file

I am writing code for my android application, i am adding using @+id/id_name in the code
But this is not getting updated in R.java
How can I update it manually and also how to give this 0x7f080007 numbering?

Comment: do not write manually. Eclipse itelf maintain the id in R.java file

Comment: clean your project.That will solve your issue. R.java file will be created again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never update your R.java manually. Clean your project and try, It will update your `R.java` file.

Make sure that there is no error in any of the xml file. If one of the xml that contain error `R.java` file does not update.

Check with following steps:

```
1. Check all of your XML,
2.  Project -> Clean,
3. Right click -> Fix Project Properties,
4. Repeat.
5. Maybe try restarting Eclipse
```

Note: check `R.java` package imported in your project. If it's `android.R` just replace with your `packagename.R`

Comment: I am not getting any error but when I tried to clean I am getting error as
jewel_info.xml:5: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'title' with value '@string/action_compose')

Comment: @Shri It means you didn't declare action_compose in your string.xml file.

Comment: declare action_compose in your string.xml file.

Comment: Hey thanks alot I cleared all the errors and then cleaned the project it worked Thanks alot...

Comment: Glad to help you :) Congrats happy codding.

Comment: One more question please when I was clearing the errors,i was getting error for android:layout_toRightOf uses resource android.R some what like this why so?????

Comment: Paste entire error here. So that I Can understand what are you trying to say.

Answer (score 1):

Never update R.java manually. Check you don't have duplicate ids, close eclipse, re-open it, clean the project and build (usually is automatic).

Answer (score 0):

You definitely do NOT want to manually update the R file.
Try cleaning and building. If you get a lot of compile issues when you do this, then you have define something incorrectly in you resource folder. 
Make sure the names of all your drawables are all lowercase with no numerics, make sure all xml files are properly formed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I think you have imported android.R.Please remove below code in your project. And the clean and build you project

```
import android.R;
```